# How can I set the width of a row of multiple inputs to a percentage of the browser window width when some inputs are of fixed size?

Tags: html, css

Title says it all.  I have a row of inputs including text fields, selects, radio buttons and checkboxes, and I want the total width of the row to be a percentage of the screen but I also want some of the individual inputs to remain a constant width.  I've tried putting all the row inputs inside `<div>` tags and setting the css of the `div` to `width:100%` but it doesn't do anything. I think that's because I've set the css of some of the inputs to a specific number of pixels.

```html
<div style="width:90%">
    <span style="width:100%; display:block">
      <input type="text" style="width:50px">
      <input type="text" style="width:33%">
      <input type="text" style="width:33%">
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap them inside a div, if you want them to stay fixed in the row and not wrap in the next row then make use of a flexbox, where you can keep some of the elements width fixed while others are flexible depending on the viewport resize.

Comment: And in before you ask a solution, post the minimal code and show what effort did you make to achieve what you ask.

Comment: I'm not a professional web developer, I'm just making a website for fun.  I do know the basics but not enough to achieve what I want in this case.  I did some googling but couldn't find the answer to this specific question.  I did post the minimal code I tried.  Flex is not an option because it isn't supported on my Microsoft phone, and looking at my site on that phone is the reason I want to have inputs resize to fit the browser width.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay thanks, I updated my question with a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meler,

It seems you've not considered the basics like inputs usually behave as inline elements. Please make sure that you have made them block to occupy the width in %

eg:

```
<div style="width:90%">
    <span style="width:100%">some text</span>
//this should not work until you make span as 'display:block' 
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I put my inputs for the row between `<div style="width:90%">
<span style="display:block; width:100%;">` and `</span></div>` but it is doing literally nothing.  When I resize the browser window some inputs get moved to the second line without any of them resizing.

Comment: I updated my OP with a very basic snippet.  My true code is awfully long but I will post it if it helps.

Comment: It seems to only work up to a certain points after which one field gets pushed to the next line.  That'll do though so thanks